# How to add days of the week to the existing date's column in Rstudio

Tags: r

For my analysis, I need to add days of the week to the dates in Rstudio. My data starts from the first day of January ( 2019-01-01 00:00:00) and time steps are 5 minutes therefore, the second term is "2019-01-01 00:05:00 to the last day of the year. Unfortunately, some rows are missing and for example, in one case next reading after 2019-05-01 10:05:00 can be 2019-05-17 23:05:00. How can I assign days of the week to my dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this work? First, we convert the date into the magic R format, and then extract it back in the format we want.

```r
posix <- strptime(x = "2019-01-01 00:00:00", 
                  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
strftime(posix, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %A")
```

Here, we're essentially exporting it in the exact same format, plus the %A operator that corresponds to the weekday.

Comment: How can I implement this code for my entire "DateTime" column?

Comment: I have used the following code to implement this code for the entire DateTime column:
posix <- strptime(x = "dt$DateTime", 
                  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

strftime(posix, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %A")

However, it returns NA.

Comment: Is that code exactly what you used? With quotes around the "dt$DateTime" it doesn't refer to a column but instead literally just the string "dt$DateTime".